# Compile SQLite with MDK-ARM

Tags: sqlite, keil

While compiling SQLite amalgamation with MDK-ARM(Keil) I have met errors:

```
..\..\Libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3081101\sqlite3.c(25838): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "sys/types.h": No such file or directory
..\..\Libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3081101\shell.c(59): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "pwd.h": No such file or directory
```

I can see many includes of linux headers, they will not be found too. What can I do to provide them? May be use another STL?

Comment: SQLite is expecting that the system you are compiling for has an OS, and the associated POSIX libraries. You'll have to check how to compile it for an embedded system.

Comment: Use another normal compiler, not this guano.